# Communicating with PX4 via ROS

Tags: drake

I want to control a quadrotor in the MultibodyPlant.It includes a sdf model which has a quadrotor and a payload. I find that Gazebo can load the sdf model. I just want to control the quadrotor with PX4 via ROS. Is that possible?

Answer (score 0):

The general approach would be to create a `Diagram` that includes the `MultibodyPlant` + the necessary `RosSubscriber` and `RosPublisher` systems from the [drake-ros](https://github.com/RobotLocomotion/drake-ros/blob/main/drake_ros/core/ros_subscriber_system.h) package. Then you can run the Drake executable with `simulator.set_target_realtime_rate(1.0)` and it can serve as the simulation-based "twin" for your quadrotor hardware.

Of course, Drake offers many different sensor models that you might add to the diagram and publish on additional ROS2 topics as needed.